# Alternatives to fsockopen - (very slow)?

Tags: php, javascript, proxy, vpn, fsockopen

Does anyone know an alternative to @fsockopen? I'm trying to detect proxies -- user hits site, grab users IP address, then use @fsockopen to see if they are using a specific port.Using this function is BY FAR the most reliable for detecting, outside of banning specific IPs / IP Patterns. However, it's very slow and un-acceptable for users visiting my site. Is there any other options, or a way to make it faster? And no setting the timeout of the function to 1 second doesn't help :P.

Example code:

```
 if ( $sock = @fsockopen($ _server['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errst, 1) ) { echo "proxy!"; }
```

Can curl achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add clarification what you are trying to achieve and show us some code. What do you mean by detecting proxies and why does setting the timeout has to do with it?

Comment: I mean detect if a visitor is viewing the site under a proxy. IE: takes _server['REMOTE_ADDR'] and determines based off that if it's a proxy. For the second piece, most think that the parameter in fsockopen - "timeout" (ex: fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30) -- 30 seconds is the timeout here), effects the "slowness" I am referring to. It does not.

Comment: How exactly are you determining if someone is viewing a site over a proxy? Are you trying to connect to their IP via port 80?

Comment: Essentially yes:
if ( $sock = @fsockopen($ _server['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, 1) ) {
echo "proxy!";
}

Answer (score 1):

Test for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`:

```
$is_proxy = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
```

It's faster and more accurate than your current method.